# VBA with excel - "If a cell contains "thisString" append "this text" onto the end a call on the same row in Column F"

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

It has been a very long time since using VBA, would someone be able to help with a macro that would search a rather large excel sheet which would look for specific trigger words within one column (A) and if found it would append "someText" into into a cell in column F on the same row?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: You'll want to try looping. http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html

Comment: loop the rows, using a loop, then use INSTR to find and then string & string will concatenate, so range("a1").value & "SUFFIX" for ex

Comment: I'd rather go with `Range.Find` (see the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff839746.aspx)). It's way more efficient than looping if the sheet is large compared to the number of occurrences. Please show us some code.

Comment: you could do this very easily: If you found the string, paste the cell value in a string variable, then give the cell the new value of the string variable as well as your "someText". Combining strings with variables can be done with a "&" (Example variable CellValue, some text: Cells(XY).Value = CellValue & "This is the added text"

Answer (score 1):

This code find all occurence of the Key Word in Column A and write the text in Column F of each of them.

```
Sub test2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ValueToFind As String, TextToInput As String
Dim c

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet

ValueToFind = InputBox("Enter the value that you are looking")

With ws1.Columns("A:A")

   Set c = .Find(ValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

   If Not c Is Nothing Then
    TextToInput = InputBox("Enter the text")
         firstAddress = c.Address

    Do
        .Cells(c.Row, "F") = TextToInput
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
Sub AddStringIf()

    Dim columnA As Range
    Dim triggerArray
    Dim IsInArray As Boolean
    Dim stringToAdd

    stringToAdd = "Something"
    triggerArray = Array("TriggerWord1", "TriggerWord2", "TriggerWord3")
    Set columnA = Range("A1:A100")

    For Each cell In columnA
        IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, triggerArray, 0))
        If IsInArray Then
            cell.Offset(, 5) = cell.Value & stringToAdd
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```